# Cómo calcular la edad mediante el carnet de identidad

Tags: python

Quisiera calcular la edad tomando los 6 primeros números del carnet de identidad y poner un *input* el cual solo puedan introducir 11 números, que son los números del carnet de identidad.

Ejemplo de un número de carnet de identidad: `82101569553`

Los 6 primeros números indican la fecha de nacimiento que sería, en este caso, año 1982 mes 10 y día 15.

```
from datetime import date
ci = "82101569553"
fecha_nac = ci[:6] # para que tome los 6 primeros números
ordenar_fecha= date(int(fecha_nac[:2]), int(fecha_nac[2:4]),int(fecha_nac[:-2])
print(ordenar_fecha)
```

Ahora lo que devuelve es `0082-10-15`. Como le digo que nació en 1982, y no en 0082, con respecto al año igual cuando alguien haya nacido en el año 2000 me pondría 0000. Para poder restarle esta fecha de nacimiento con la fecha actual.

Comment: Prueba con: `ordenar_fecha = date(1900+int(fecha_nac[:2]), int(fecha_nac[2:4]),int(fecha_nac[-2:]))`

Comment: Con lo del año superior a 2000, no me imagino como vas a hacer. Si alguien tiene más de 100 años como identificas que nació en 1910 o en 2010?

Comment: Tengo curiosidad, ¿de qué país son eso números de identidad? En España son diferentes y tiene un carácter de control al final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mi me funcionó de la siguiente forma:

```
import datetime
ci = "82101569553"
fecha_nac = ci[:6] # para que tome los 6 primeros números
fecha = fecha_nac[:2] + fecha_nac[2:4] + fecha_nac[-2:]
ordenar_fecha= datetime.datetime.strptime(fecha, '%y%m%d')
if ordenar_fecha.year > 2005:
   ordenar_fecha = ordenar_fecha.replace(year=ordenar_fecha.year-100)
print(ordenar_fecha.date()) # Para convertir el datatime a date usa el método date()
```

Espero te sirva.